Formatting inside the [prelim one column text] of \twocolumn
I am using the square bracket notation of \twocolumn[] to do a preliminary one column text before formatting in two columns. However I struggle to make style apply inside the preliminary area:
Here is a minimal example:
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}

\begin{document}        
    
    \twocolumn[
    \section{INTRODUCTION}  
    \par {\lipsum[1-3]}
    ]
    
    \subsection{FIRST}  
    \lipsum[3-6]
    
\end{document}


My parskip of 12 pt is correctly applied in the twocolumn area, but not within the preliminary, one column area. Any idea why and how to fix this? Thank you in advance.


The spanning box is essentially a \parbox and like all such boxes, several settings are normalized, including \parskip, but you can set it back.

\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}

\begin{document}        
    
    \twocolumn[\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}
    \section{INTRODUCTION}  
    \par {\lipsum[1-3]}
    \bigskip
    ]
    
    \subsection{FIRST}  
    \lipsum[3-6]
    
\end{document}


Many thanks, it was not clear it was a parbox, now this explains it. One thing to take into consideration is spacing after the parbox then, to avoid that the 2-column text following touches the prelim text.

@EricFernandez yes that's why Iadded a \bigskip
